# How to display a JavaScript ID on page as well as send same ID to another page

Tags: javascript, php, html

The code below displays and updates the time like a stop watch and works fine.  But as well as displaying the running time, I need to send the "register" ID to another PHP page.  The "register" ID value is not passing.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
        <script>
        function startTime() {

        var today = new Date();
        var local_year= today.getFullYear();
        var local_month= today.getMonth()+1;
        if (local_month < 10) {local_month = "0" + local_month};
        var local_day= today.getDate();
        if (local_day < 10) {local_day = "0" + local_day};
        var h = today.getHours();
        if (h < 10) {h = "0" + h};
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        if (m < 10) {m = "0" + m};
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        if (s < 10) {s = "0" + s};
        
        var db_registration_date = local_year + "" + local_month + "" + local_day + "" +  h + "" + m + "" + s;

        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = local_month + "-" + local_day + "-" + local_year + "&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
        h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

        document.getElementById('register').innerHTML = db_registration_date;

        }

    </script>

    <body onload="startTime();" style="max-height:auto;margin-top:auto;margin-bottom:auto;" >
        <html>

        <span id="txt"></span>

        <form action="menu_scriptV3.php" method="post">

            <input type="hidden" name="last_customer" value="<?php echo $last_customer ?>" 
            <input type="hidden" name="local_day_name2" id="local_day_name" />

            <input type="hidden" name="reg_date" id="register" />


            <button  class="center-block" type="submit" style="color:black;padding:40px;font-size:35px;width:550px;padding:40px" >
                Last Customer
            </button>
            
        </form>

    </html>
    </body>
```

Comment: Just a quick comment: It looks like you are passing it named as `"reg_date"`.

Comment: As @SebastianVittersø highlighted if you are submitting the form to  'menu_scriptV3.php' then traditional behaviour of form data being submitted based on 'name' attributes. If you want to send ID (register) then make AJAX call where you can control by what means data will be sent. Otherwise consider your use case to rely on 'name' attribute.

Comment: Hey Sebastian, Yes I am passing it as reg_date is that wrong?  I am a real Novice at JavaScript.  And Tank1322 could you give me an example.  What I have above is wrong, but is what I have come up with after two days of struggling.  Thanks you guys!

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do should be relatively straight-forward and trivial, so it should be easy to solve / debug what the issue is, however, there are little things that could be tripping you up.

Just make sure you cover everything, failing that try some rudamentary debugging techniques.

**Try fixing your HTML**

Change this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="last_customer" value="<?php echo $last_customer ?>"
```

To this line:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="last_customer" value="<?php echo $last_customer ?>" />
```

**Debug the request:**

When trying to debug, see what your request looks like by analysing the request data submitted using the network tab in chrome inspector, or just var_dump() ing the $_POST variable inside menu_scriptV3.php

```
// line 1 inside menu_scriptV3.php
<?php var_dump($_POST); exit(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value you want to pass is inside the input field, then you can use javascript to push it to another page.
Try this.

```js
$('#push').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
  var name = button.data('push_name')

  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-body #push_name').val(name);

})
```

```
<input type="hidden" name="reg_date" id="reg_push" />
<?php $reg = 'reg_date'; ?>

<button type="button" name="send" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#push" data-push_name="<?= $reg ?>" >Send</button>


<!-- This will go to the new php page -->
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="push_name" name="push_name">
```